# jackson datetime pattern not displaying timezone correctly

Tags: java, xml, jackson

My class:

```
@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ", timezone="UTC")
protected XMLGregorianCalendar dateTime;
```

My date instance:

```
XMLGregorianCalendar dateTime = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar("2013-04-10T15:27:37+01:00");
obj.setDateTime(dateTime);
```

The translation:

```
ObjectMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
xmlMapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
return "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>" + xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(object);
```

The output:

```
<DateTime>2013-04-10T14:27:37+0000</DateTime>
```

Expected output:

```
<DateTime>2013-04-10T15:27:37+01:00</DateTime>
```

Why is the timezone and timezone format getting lost in translation?

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the Timezone for Jackson to UTC. See your annotation: `@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ", timezone="UTC")`
I think the output is exactly what you would expect since UTC has the timezoneoffset +0000

Comment: What do I need to do to make it "`+01:00`"?

Comment: Change the timezone attribute to the Timezone you expect. +0100 would be some sort of CET (Europe/Berlin or Paris for example)

Comment: What about the missing `:`?

Comment: If you can tell me how to remove the GMT from this line's output. I'll mark your answer as correct: `@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz", timezone="GMT+1")`

Comment: I don´t exactly know how to change this...but i would guess you would find that information in the DateFormat API of Java

Comment: Just put CET for GMT

Comment: It seems there's only two ways to display timezone format:

`+0100` and `GMT+01:00`